# is there any place in a swift project i can set the title on NavigationController at once?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am pretty new in Swift and would like to get help for the following issue.

I got many viewControllers need to be set the Navigation Title by getting the value from CoreData.

I know that i could set the Navigation title in "viewDidLoad" Method for each viewController by following code

```
self.Title = "Home"
```

And i also know that i could create a base viewController and let all viewController to inherit from it which i don't want by this way.

Is there any other places (ways) that i can set the Navigation title at once with the value get from CoreData? (i.e. AppDelegate? )

it would be helpful if there is an example for me. thxs